# Backgroundworker to return a string[] array

Tags: c#, background, backgroundworker

I'm writing a program that uses a `backgroundWorker1_doWork()` to recursively populating a string[] array and return it through `DoWorkEventArgs e`, how do you do that? Thank

Comment: This is not a "get tips" site, it is a question/answer site.  Please post your current code, and revise your post into a specific question that can have a specific answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you can set `e.Result` in `backgroundWorker1_doWork()` event handler with the `string[]` array and then use it in `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

The following is the code which I have written in winforms.

```
    BackgroundWorker work = null;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        work = new BackgroundWorker();
        work.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(work_DoWork);
        work.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(work_RunWorkerCompleted);
        work.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void work_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arr = (e.Result as string[]);

        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item);    
        }
    }

    void work_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arr = new string[3];
        arr[0] = "aa";
        arr[1] = "bb";
        arr[2] = "cc";

        e.Result = arr;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks samar, but that result is just a string, how do I get a string[] array to return?

Comment: What stops you from giving e.Result the required array? Check my updated answer.

Comment: If this answer was useful to you then please tick mark it as answer and/or upvote it. :)